# How to implement in app payment in android?

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase

I am looking for best practices while developing in-app payment apps on android?

How do you you store the data on android so that the information is not wiped off by an upgrade nor is it easily visibly to prying eyes? The data essentially says that this user has already paid for the app.

Comment: By 'upgrade' do you mean an app upgrade or an OS/firmware upgrade? App data is retained, except when the app is uninstalled or if the user uses the 'clear data' button in Settings.

Comment: app upgrade and since you mentioned it now OS upgrade too. Right now its a roundabout way of contacting a webservice and checking phone number of users SIM. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with many apps that does in-app billing, across other mobile platforms like Java ME, BlackBerry, BREW etc. The one sure way of doing this is to keep information on server. The app can do the processing, and/or any other kind of billing transactions, but the final authority for this should be server side. That way, app upgrades, uninstall etc, will not have an impact on billing (assuming we tie the user to a unique identifier like SubNo, client ID, Phone number, MEID etc).